# Serve static content in Go Web Language

Tags: go

I want to serve **html, css and js file** at **server using GO language**. Tell me the optimized way to do that.

**Restriction**: Don't have to use any framework.

Comment: Why do I get the the feeling you didn't spend one second searching for a solution on your own? All you need is right there in the standard library. http://godoc.org/net/http#FileServer Also, there is a lot of information available on this: https://www.google.de/search?q=go+serve+static+content

Comment: Started it, but haven't got any good content.

Comment: I'd say the response from lukad is the answer you seek. Go has great documentation on using the standard libraries for these kinds of questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
package main
import "net/http"
func main() {
        http.ListenAndServe(":8080",http.FileServer(http.Dir("/path/to/static/content")))
}
```

http://code.google.com/p/go-wiki/wiki/HttpStaticFiles

Answer (score 3):

One good starting point is the [library **negroni**](https://github.com/codegangsta/negroni):

- it is *not* a framework:  It is a library that is designed to work directly with net/http.
- it has multiple renders, like [unrolled/render](https://github.com/unrolled/render) for easily rendering JSON, XML, and HTML templates: that can gives idea as to serve other content as well.